# Get an item from List<Claim> in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, claims

I am creating a list of claims while login:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, user.UserName),
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim("Testing", "test")
            };
```

There is no authorisation for the Login method so the claims have not been saved or the cookie hasn't been created but the list contains the userId created and I want to save it in an activity log (table):

```
var activityLog = new AccessLogEntity
            {
                ActivityDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
                UserId = ## get from claims (List<Claim>
            };

            await _context.tbl_ActivityLogs.AddAsync(activityLog);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I didn't fully understand the question or maybe I didn't understand it at all.)

I have never used Claims or ASP.NET core. However, if the second parameter in your constructor is the UserId you want to get, as in

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, /* -----> */ user.UserName /*<------ this one here */ )   ,
                new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim("Testing", /* -----> */"test"/* <----- Or this */)
            };
```

You can easily do that with

```
claims[0 /* Or whichever you want to get*/].Value;
```

Full code

```
var activityLog = new AccessLogEntity
{
    ActivityDate = DateTime.UtcNow,
    UserId = claims[i /*Or whatever*/].Value;
};

await _context.tbl_ActivityLogs.AddAsync(activityLog);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Edit:

If you don't want to hardcode an index but rather get the username from the name identifier, use something like this:

```
public string getUsernameFromID(List<Claim> claims, string id)
{

   foreach (var cl in claims)
   {
       if (cl.Type == id)
       {

           return cl.Value;     
       }
    }
    return "";
}
```

Use it like:

```
getUsernameFromID(claims, "Testing");  // Which returns "test"
```

which in this case will return "test" and it indeed does!

Am I missing something here??? I am pretty sure I didn't get your question...

Comment: This would be hardcoded where I can use indexing and I want to avoid that since I might add/remove claims in future. And want to know how to retrieve an item from List<T> using any element description or something, for the lack of proper term